# Can't import aws_security_group.sg_name, would collide with an existing resource

Tags: terraform

I did terraform apply which leads to creating new security group and removing one security group.

Then I tried terraform import but I got this error

Can't import aws_security_group.online_ec2_security_group, would collide with an existing resource.

Please, if anyone knows how can I replace the new security group with the old security group that would be a great help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terraform shows this error if there is already a remote object associated with the given resource address. You can see Terraform's record of that existing object by running the following command:

```
terraform state show aws_security_group.online_ec2_security_group
```

If you want Terraform to forget about that existing object (leaving it still existing in AWS, but no longer tracked by Terraform) then you can remove it directly from the Terraform state:

```
terraform state rm aws_security_group.online_ec2_security_group
```

After running that, Terraform will no longer have any record that this object exists, so if you want to delete it you'll need to do so manually outside of Terraform.

Once Terraform has "forgotten" the old object, you should be able to import the new object in its place.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try this approach and let you know about the result